# Cap product for Hochschild (co)chains

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

Let $A$ be an associative algebra and $M$ be an $A$-bimodule. Then we can form the Hochschild cochains $C^\bullet(A,A)$ and chains $C_\bullet(A, M)$ and define a pairing (cap product)
$$
  C^\bullet(A,A) \otimes C_\bullet(A, M)
  \xrightarrow{\enspace\frown\enspace}
  C_\bullet(A, M)
$$
in the following way: for $f\in C^n(A,A)$ and $g = m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p \in C_p(A,M)$,
$$f\frown g := 
\begin{cases}
  (-1)^n m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n & \text{for $p \geq n$},\\
  0 & \text{for $p < n$},
\end{cases}
  $$
which is an element of $C_{n-p}(A, M)$.

There is the following simple assertion:

**Proposition.** $C_\bullet(A, M)$ is a differential graded module over $C^\bullet(A, A)$ with respect to the cap product, i.e.,
$$
  d(f \frown g) = d(f) \frown g + (-1)^{\deg(f)} f \frown d(g) \,.
  \tag{1}
$$
The reference for this is
https://pbelmans.ncag.info/assets/hh-2018-notes.pdf page 24 or [http://www.math.tamu.edu/~sarah.witherspoon/pub/HH-25August2018.pdf](http://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Esarah.witherspoon/pub/HH-25August2018.pdf) page 17.

This looked to be an easy exercise, but even in simple cases the computations went wrong. For example, let $f \in C^1(A, A)$ and $g = m \otimes a_1 \otimes a_2 \in C_2(A, M)$. Then $f \frown g = -m f(a_1) \otimes a_2$ and the left-hand side of $(1)$ is
$$
  d(f \frown g)
  = d(-m f(a_1) \otimes a_2)
  = -(m f(a_1) a_2 - a_2 m f(a_1))
  = a_2 m f(a_1) - m f(a_1) a_2 \,.
$$
At the same time, the right-hand side is
\begin{align*}
  {}&
  d(f) \frown g + (-1)^{\deg(f)} f \frown d(g) \\
  ={}& m \cdot d(f)(a_1 \otimes a_2) - f \frown (m a_1 \otimes a_2 - m \otimes a_1 a_2 + a_2 m \otimes a_1) \\
  ={}& m a_1 f(a_2) - m f(a_1 a_2) + m f(a_1) a_2 + m a_1 f(a_2) - m f(a_1 a_2) + a_2 m f(a_1) \\
  ={}& 2 m a_1 f(a_2) - 2 m f(a_1 a_2) + m f(a_1) a_2 + a_2 m f(a_1) \,.
\end{align*}
These two expressions obviously do not coincide.

Where I was wrong?

**Edit.** It seems that there is a sign mistake in the definition of the cap product given above and the right definition should be
$$
  f \frown g := m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n \,.
$$

Comment: @Jendrik Stelzner Yes, at least for this simple case it is true, but it doesn't violate the definition of a dg module, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
\begin{equation}
\tag{$\ast$}
    d(f \cap g)
  = (-1)^n d(f) \cap g + (-1)^n f \cap d(g)
  = (-1)^{|f|} \Bigl( d(f) \cap g + f \cap d(g) \Bigr).
\end{equation}
for all $f \in \operatorname{C}^n(A) = \operatorname{Hom}_k(A^{\otimes n}, A)$ and $g \in \operatorname{C}_p(A, M) = M \otimes A^{\otimes p}$ (the computation is at the end of this post).

From what I understand this may or may not be a problem, depending on what we are planning to do:

- The equation $(\ast)$ sufficies to show that the cup product descends to a well-defined bilinear map $\operatorname{HH}^\bullet(A) \times \operatorname{HH}_\bullet(A,M) \to \operatorname{HH}_\bullet(A,M)$, (nearly) making $\operatorname{HH}_\bullet(A,M)$ into a graded $\operatorname{HH}^\bullet(A)$-module as claimed in Witherspoon’s text (see below for a possible problem).
- From what I understand the Hochschild chain complex $\operatorname{C}_\bullet(A,M)$ does not become a dg $\operatorname{C}^\bullet(A)$-module as we would instead need the sign convention
  \begin{equation*}
  \tag{$\ast\ast$}
    d(f \cap g) = d(f) \cap g + (-1)^n f \cap d(g).
  \end{equation*}

But I need to point out that there are some things about the cap product which confuse me, and the correct understanding of which may show that there are actually no problems.

- It seems that both Witherspoon and Belmans try to define a left module structure on $\operatorname{C}_\bullet(A,M)$ and $\operatorname{HH}_\bullet(A,M)$ via the cap product (where $\operatorname{C}^\bullet(A)$ and $\operatorname{HH}^\bullet(A)$ are equipped with the cup product).
  But it seem to me that
  $$
      (f_1 \cup f_2) \cap g
    = f_2 \cap (f_1 \cap g),
  $$
  so that the cap product actually defines a right module structure.
  (Maybe this is no problem for the Hochschild (co)homology because the cup product is graded-commutative on $\operatorname{HH}^\bullet(A)$?)
- Because $\operatorname{C}^\bullet(A)$ is a cochain complex but $\operatorname{C}_\bullet(A,M)$ is a chain complex there might be some more signs hidden in the definition of an dg module (as both differentials go in different directions).
  I suspect that we want that the flipped complex $\widetilde{\operatorname{C}}^\bullet(A,M) = \operatorname{C}_{-\bullet}(A,M)$ to be dg $\operatorname{C}^\bullet(A)$-module with the sign convention as in $(\ast\ast)$, which would then mean that we always want the sign convention $(\ast\ast)$.

---

Now the calculations:

To show $(\ast)$ we start by computing the terms $d(f \cap g)$, $f \cap d(g)$ and $d(f) \cap g$.
For $n \leq p$ all three terms are zero, so let’s only look at $n > p$.
Let’s also assume that $g$ is a pure tensor $g = m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p$.

First term:
\begin{align*}
   &\,
       d( f \cap  (m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p ) )
  \\
  =&\,
       (-1)^n d( m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p )
  \\
  =&\, (-1)^n \Big[
           m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) a_{n+1} \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
  \\
   &\, \phantom{(-1)^n \Big[}
          + \sum_{i=1}^{p-n-1} (-1)^i
           m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+i} a_{n+i+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p \\
   &\, \phantom{(-1)^n \Big[}  
          + (-1)^{p-n} a_p m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{p-1}
       \Big]
  \\
  =&\,   (-1)^n m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) a_{n+1} \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
       \tag{1}
  \\
   &\, + (-1)^n \sum_{i=1}^{p-n-1} (-1)^i
         m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+i} a_{n+i+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
       \tag{2}
  \\
   &\, + (-1)^p a_p m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{p-1}
       \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Second Term:
\begin{align*}
   &\,
       d(f) \cap (m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p)
  \\
  =&\,
       (-1)^{n+1} m \, d(f)(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+1}) \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
  \\
  =&\,
       (-1)^{n+1} m
       \Big[
           a_1 f (a_2 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+1})
  \\
   &\, \phantom{(-1)^{n+1} m \Big[}
         + \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_i a_{i+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+1})
  \\
   &\, \phantom{(-1)^{n+1} m \Big[}
         + (-1)^{n+1} f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) a_{n+1}
       \Big]
       \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
  \\
  =&\,
         (-1)^{n+1} m a_1 f(a_2 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+1}) \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
       \tag{4}
  \\
   &\,
       + (-1)^{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i
         m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_i a_{i+1} \otimes a_{n+1}) \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
       \tag{5}
  \\
   &\,
       + m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) a_{n+1} \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
       \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Third term:
\begin{align*}
   &\,
       f \cap d(m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p)
  \\
  =&\, f \cap \Big[
           m a_1 \otimes a_2 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
  \\
   &\, \phantom{f \cap \Big[}
         + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (-1)^i m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_i a_{i+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
  \\
   &\, \phantom{f \cap \Big[}
         + (-1)^p a_p m \otimes a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{p-1}
       \Big]
  \\
  =&\,
         (-1)^n m a_1 f(a_2 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+1}) \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
       \tag{4}
  \\
   &\, + (-1)^n \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i
         m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_i a_{i+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+1}) \otimes a_{n+2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
       \tag{5}
  \\
   &\, + (-1)^n \sum_{i=1}^{p-n-1} (-1)^{n+i}
         m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{n+i} a_{n+i+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_p
       \tag{2}
  \\
   &\, + (-1)^{n+p} a_p m f(a_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n) \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes a_{p-1}
       \tag{3}
\end{align*}

We now want to combine these three terms in an equation of the form
$$
  d(f \cap g) = \varepsilon_1 d(f) \cap g + \varepsilon_2 f \cap d(g)
$$
for suitable signs $\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2 = \pm 1$, which may depend on the degrees $n$ and $p$.
We get from $(1)$ that $\varepsilon_1 = (-1)^n$ and from $(2)$ that $\varepsilon_2 = (-1)^n$. This is also compatible with $(3)$, and the additional terms of the forms $(4)$ and $(5)$ cancel each other out because $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon_2$.
We thus find that
$$
    d(f \cap g)
  = (-1)^n d(f) \cap g + (-1)^n f \cap d(g)
  = (-1)^{|f|} \Bigl( d(f) \cap g + f \cap d(g) \Bigr).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. Now it is clear that the source of confusion was lurking in the definition of the cap product and I made an edit in my original post. I hope that everyone has learnt something from that.

Answer (score 2):

I will do the computation using bar symbols.
(It is really hard from here to understand why the author in *loc. cit.*
prefers the many tensors. Notations are important to fix the calculus.)

There are always sign conventions from textbook to textbook,
here i am doing the computations barely without checking the reference.

We have for $f$ of degree one, and $g=m[a|b]$ the following
computation using bar symbols:
$$
\begin{aligned}
g &= m[a|b]\ ,\\
f\frown g
& =mf(a)[b]\ ,\\[2mm]
d(f\frown g)
&= -mf(a)d[b] \\
&= -mf(a)\; (b[]-[]b) \\
&= -mf(a)b[] +mf(a)[]b\\
&= -\color{blue}{mf(a)b[]} +\color{red}{bmf(a)[]}\\
&\qquad\text{and here is the sense for the bar symbols,}\\[2mm]
\underbrace{df}_{\in C^2}\frown g
&= df\frown m[a|b]\\
&= m\;df[a|b]\\
&= m\;fd[a|b]\\
&= m\;f\;(a[b]-[ab]+[a]b)\\
&= m\;(af(b)[]-f(ab)[]+\color{red}{f(a)[]b})\\[2mm]
f\frown dg
&= f\frown m\; d[a|b]\\
&= f\frown m\; (a[b]-[ab]+[a]b)\\
&= m\; (af(b)[]-f(ab)[]+\color{blue}{f(a)b[]})\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Subtracting the two terms $df\frown g$ and $f\frown g$ from each other
produces the cancellation of the unmarked terms, and the red/blue term in
the result corresponds to the one in $d(f\frown g)$.

Here, we use the convention that scalars after the bar symbol, e.g. as in
$mf(a)[]b$ can be **"cyclically"** moved in front (via the tensor product of that $A^e=A\otimes A^{\text{opp}}$,
from the opp-part) to the $m\in M$, which has as structure of bimodule.
(It is hard to do cyclic (co)homology without a notation supporting the cyclicity.)

Comment: For me the bar notation is a little bit confusing and it seems that now it is abandoned in modern textbooks, e.g. Weibel, Loday etc., where they use tensors through the identification $C_n(A,M)=M\otimes_{A^e}A^{\otimes(n+2)}≅M\otimes A^{\otimes n}$. Can you please elaborate your answer using tensors? It would be very helpful for me.